# Pyparser how to parse similar looking delimited and non delimited strings

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

How can I parse the two types of strings below using two separate parsers - one for each pattern?

```
from pyparsing import *    
dd = """
  wire         c_f_g;
  wire         cl_3_f_g4;

   x_y abc_d
      (.c_l (cl_dclk_001l),
       .c_h (cl_m1dh_ff),
       .ck     (b_f_1g));
```

I am able to parse them independently using parsers below (respectively):

```
# For the lines containing wire
printables_less_semicolon = printables.replace(';','')
wireDef = Literal("wire") + Word( printables)

# For the nested pattern
instanceStart = Word( printables ) + Word( printables_less_semicolon )
u = nestedExpr(opener="(", closer=")", ignoreExpr=dblSlashComment)
t = OneOrMore(instanceStart + u + Word( ";" ) + LineEnd())
print instanceStart.parseString(dd)
```

If you run the above code, the`instanceStart` parser matches the wire line. How can I reliably differentiate between the two?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want... Parsers which match the whole string and give the two different expressions in the result dict? Or parsers which matches for each line? Give a syntactically correct complete example and the output you get plus the output you want.

Comment: Actually, I am very new to parsers and I am starting to ramp up as I, unfortunately, have to parse some Verilog. I think I have found a solution to my problem. it would be great if you can provide your insights in the solution that I have posted below

Comment: A Verilog parser is included in the examples directory of the pyparsing source distribution, if that would give you some ideas on your project.

Comment: The Verilog parser in the examples section is a much more complete one! I will have to port over my application to that one soon! Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution that works (definitely not the best).

```
    printables_less_semicolon = printables.replace(';','')

bracketStuff    = Group(QuotedString("(", escChar=None, multiline=True, endQuoteChar=");"))
ifDef           = Group(QuotedString("`ifdef", endQuoteChar="`endif", multiline=True))
theEnd          = Word( "endmodule" )
nestedConns     = Group(nestedExpr(opener="(", closer=")", ignoreExpr=dblSlashComment))
instance        = Regex('[\s?|\r\n?].*\(')
othersWithSc    = Group(Word (printables) + Word (printables_less_semicolon) + Literal(";"))
othersWithoutSc = Word (printables) + Word (printables_less_semicolon) + NotAny(Literal(";"))
```

A combination of the above parsers allow me to parse the files in the format that I am dealing with.
An example input:

```
ts2 = """
module storyOfFox ( andDog, 
        JLT);
  input andDog;
  output JLT;

   `ifdef quickFox
 `include "gatorade"
 `include "chicken" 
`endif 

   wire         hello;
   wire         and;
   wire         welcome;


   the quick
      (.brown (fox),
       .jumps (over),
       .the (lazy),
       .dog    (and),
       .the (dog),
       .didNot    (likeIt));

    theDog thenWent
      (// Waiver unused
       .on (),
       // Waiver unused
       .to (),
       .sueThe (foxFor),
       .jumping (andBeingTooQuick),
       .TheDog    (wasHailedAsAHero),
       .endOf (Story));


  endmodule
"""
```

Parser that works to parse the above:

```
try:
    tp  = othersWithoutSc + Optional(bracketStuff) + Optional(ZeroOrMore(othersWithSc)) + Optional( Group( ZeroOrMore( othersWithoutSc + nestedConns ) ) ) + theEnd
    tpI = Group( ZeroOrMore( othersWithoutSc + nestedConns +  Word( ";" ) ) )
    tpO = Each( [Optional(ZeroOrMore(othersWithSc)), Optional(ifDef)] )
    tp  = othersWithoutSc + Optional(bracketStuff) + tpO + Group(tpI) + theEnd
    #print othersWithoutSc.parseString("input xyz;")
    print tp.parseString(ts2)
except ParseException as x:
    print "Line {e.lineno}, column {e.col}:\n'{e.line}'".format(e=x)
```

Output obtained:

```
module
storyOfFox
[' andDog, \n        JLT']
['input', 'andDog', ';']
['output', 'JLT', ';']
[' quickFox\n `include "gatorade"\n `include "chicken" \n']
['wire', 'hello', ';']
['wire', 'and', ';']
['wire', 'welcome', ';']
[['the', 'quick', [['.brown', ['fox'], ',', '.jumps', ['over'], ',', '.the', ['lazy'], ',', '.dog', ['and'], ',', '.the', ['dog'], ',', '.didNot', ['likeIt']]], ';', 'theDog', 'thenWent', [['// Waiver unused', '.on', [], ',', '// Waiver unused', '.to', [], ',', '.sueThe', ['foxFor'], ',', '.jumping', ['andBeingTooQuick'], ',', '.TheDog', ['wasHailedAsAHero'], ',', '.endOf', ['Story']]], ';']]
endmodule
```

I do not want to accept this answer just yet as I might not have solved the real problem that I was facing before. i just found a way to get around it and get the output I need.

Comment: If that's the output you want, fine - if you want the *names* of the various parts in the output, assign via  [`setResultName`](https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.ParserElement-class.html#setResultsName) a meaningful string to them.

Comment: I am playing around with `setResultName` now. Thanks for the pointer, this will help me keep the data more organized.